# My Chrome version is Version 84.0.4147.105 but available ChromeDriver version is Version 84.0.4147.30 causing an error to launch chrome using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My chrome version is Version 84.0.4147.105  but available chrome version is Version 84.0.4147.30 its causing an error to launch chrome  through selenium what should i do apart from downgrading the chrome version .

Comment: Where can we find _available chrome version is Version 84.0.4147.30_? Can you help us please?

Comment: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html    this is the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest stable [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) is [**ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/).

This version of *ChromeDriver* is well tested for all the minor versions of [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) **Version 84.x.y.z**.

---

### Conclusion

Irespective of the difference within the minor versions of *Google Chrome*, all the `chrome=84.x.y.z` versions should work flawless using *ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30*.

Comment: There is no need to downgrade the version of chrome browser just select 84th version of any chromedriver it will work

Comment: @PRATIKBURNWAL Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: I am having this issue on linux, the browser Google Chrome 84.0.4147.135, and chromedriver version 84.0.4147.30. And getting  below error

ERROR  -     Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.

I am using serenity BDD framework.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome browsers are updating time to time so you need to use exact driver version of exe to that you can download form "https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads"
and kill driver via command prompt and refresh build and use it