# Protractor - Error Code 199: Version of Chrome doesn't support version 84

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been searching for a solution to this issue for hours on end but haven't found any poster with the exact issue.

I'm trying to use Protractor to run tests on a Ionic app my company is developing. For some reason this error started to appear recently but not some months ago, when the tests were first developed, whenever I run protractor:

```
[11:00:56] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:00:56] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[11:00:57] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://IPHERE:60779/wd/hub
[11:00:58] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: ‘mypcnamehere’, ip: ‘iphere’, os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '14.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: 0   chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010fd08c49 chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 4893769
1   chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010fca20e3 chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 4473059
2   chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010f9158fd chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 751869
3   chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010f8773b9 chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 103353
4   chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010f873696 chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 87702
5   chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010f8709b9 chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 76217
6   chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010f8a3043 chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 282691
7   chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010f89fe43 chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 269891
8   chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010f87962a chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 112170
9   chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010f87a635 chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 116277
10  chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010fcca5af chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 4638127
11  chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010fcd791b chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 4692251
12  chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010fcd76bb chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 4691643
13  chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010fcae109 chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 4522249
14  chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010fcd7ea3 chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 4693667
15  chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010fcc0073 chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 4595827
16  chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010fcef094 chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 4788372
17  chromedriver_84.0.4147.30           0x000000010fd0edb7 chromedriver_84.0.4147.30 + 4918711
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff57a77661 _pthread_body + 340
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff57a7750d _pthread_body + 0
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff57a76bf9 thread_start + 13
```

Solutions i've tried but didn't work:

- Installing chromedriver through brew
- Updating webdriver-manager
- Reinstalling Protractor, Webdriver-manager, Ionic CLI

Is any one able to help me with this issue? I'm stuck and can't do any testing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Im currently using:

- Mac OS 10.13.6
- Chrome Version: 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build)
- Node: v12.18.2 LTS
- Ionic: v5.4.16

Comment: Can you show your protractor conf.js? And please confirm only one Chrome install on your Mac.  Hope you not use `puppeteer`

Comment: same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63197147/my-chrome-version-is-version-84-0-4147-105-but-available-chromedriver-version-is

Answer (score 0):

**Try this!**

We are getting error because you don’t have **chromedriver_84.0.4147.30** in the below directory and chrome browser version updated to **Version 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build)** (64-bit)
“ ..\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium”

**Quick solution:**
Delete this selenium folder[Having driver for all browser and selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar].
Then run `update webdriver-manage` [this will recreate selenium folder and all download latest browser driver including **chromedriver_84.0.4147.30**].

Sometime this folder having old chromedriver version so it will not download the latest one. So need to delete and update the webdriver-manager.